# ApexChart Candlestick does not redraw at every state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apexcharts

I have a Chart component which gets chart data from two sources:
The first provides historic candlestick data every minute.
The second provides real time data of the current candlestick.
Both update the series object via setState.

The issue is, that **only the first source updates the chart.**

I expect that after the second source sends a current candle stick data and i update the state, the last candlestick updates on the chart, but it doesnt. It doesn't move. Although the render is triggered after both updates (from first and second source), which i can seek in the console output. Also I can see in the log that this.state.series has exactly the same format after both kind of updates.

Here is the code of my chart component:

```
import React from "react";
import Chart from "react-apexcharts";
import moment from "moment";

export default class ChartComponent extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
      series: [{data:[]}],
      options: {chart: {id: "basic-bar"}}
    }
}

componentDidMount() {     
  this.startEventSource();
}

startEventSource = ()=> {
  this.eventSource = new EventSource(`http://localhost:9000/candleStream`);
  this.eventSource.onmessage = e => this.updateChart(JSON.parse(e.data), "Minute");

  this.eventSource2 = new EventSource(`http://localhost:9000/priceStream`);
  this.eventSource2.onmessage = e => this.updatePrice(JSON.parse(e.data))         
}        

updatePrice = (newCandleData) => {

  var candleData = newCandleData.split(";");
  let momentWithoutSeconds = moment(parseInt(candleData[4])).seconds(0).milliseconds(0).valueOf();      
  let candle = [momentWithoutSeconds, parseFloat(candleData[0]), parseFloat(candleData[1]), parseFloat(candleData[2]), parseFloat(candleData[3]) ]    
  let newCandleList = this.state.series[0].data;

  if(newCandleList.filter(c => c[0] == momentWithoutSeconds).length == 0) {        
    newCandleList.push(candle);        

  } else {
    newCandleList[newCandleList.length - 1] = candle;
  }    

  this.updateChart([{data:newCandleList}], "Price");      
}    

updateChart = (data, source) => {                 
  this.setState({series: data},  console.log(source, this.state.series));
}  

render() {
  console.log("render triggered!")
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="mixed-chart">
          <Chart
            options={this.state.options}
            series={this.state.series}
            type="candlestick"
            width="1000"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );  
}
}
```

And here an example console output where the structure of series is visible:

[image]

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: The chart DOES update while I am/keep resizing the browser window.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into a similar issue today while working on a chart. I solved it in my case by setting the state values to constants in my render(). Not sure why exactly this fixed it.

```
render() {
  const { options, series } = this.state;

  console.log("render triggered!")

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="mixed-chart">
          <Chart
            options={options}
            series={series}
            type="candlestick"
            width="1000"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );  
}
```